# Convert a comma separated values string into string[] by Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Say, the field of Race in my table has values like "W,A" (white and asian), "H, W" (hispanic and white), "I" (Indian only).

How can I use Entity Framework to build this field into:
`public string[] Race {get;set;}`
or 
`public List<string> Race {get;set;}`
instead of 
`public string[] Race {get;set;}`?

I believe it should be possible. Can someone here help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Entity Framework uses partial classes you can extend it, e.g. if want to extend the entity `SomeEntityName` something like this should work:

```
public partial class SomeEntityName
{
    public string[] RaceProperties
    { get { return Race.Split(','); } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is really helpful. But is it possible to have both `get` and `set`? I am using a `CheckBoxListFor` in MVC3 as an editor for Race.

Comment: yes - you would have to map that to an update of the Race property, e.g. `set { Race = string.Join(",", value); }`